# Fill Numpy array with elements from DataFrame and with condition based on the last element of the array itself

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a `pandas` dataframe with 2 columns (longitude and latitude) ordered in descending order based on the first column.

I would like to fill a `numpy` array with the elements of the dataframe when the element of the second column is greater of the last element in the array itself.

I wrote this code:

```
coords_array = df.sort_values("lon", ascending=False).to_numpy()

new_array = np.array([coords_array[0]])

for coords in coords_array [1:]:
    if coords[1] > new_array[-1][1]:
        new_array = np.vstack([new_array, coords])
```

this code does what I want, but I would like to make it more `numpy` friendly and avoid the `for` loop.
This is also for me get more confident with `numpy`.

I was trying with `np.apply_along_axis` in combination with `lambda` function and walrus operator `:=`, this because the last element of `new_array` can change, it's not fixed, so something like this:

```
new_array = np.array([coords_array[0]])

np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: (new_array := np.vstack([new_array, coords])) if x[1] > new_array[-1][1] else _, 1, coords_array[1:])
```

but this gives me the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_array' referenced before assignment
```

it considers `new_array` as local variable; I think I am misunderstanding the walrus operator...

Any suggestion on how I can remove the `for` loop?

I am interested to understand why my code doesn't work, but I am happy with any other suggestion.

**Update**

This is a minimal example.

If the DataFrame is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"lon": [4, 2, 1, 6, 4, 5, 2], "lat": [3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 6]})
```

`coords_array` is obtained ordering `df` based on `"lon"` values:

```
coords_array
array([[6, 2],
       [5, 1],
       [4, 3],
       [4, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 6],
       [1, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

The first column of `coords_array` is `"lon"` and the second is `"lat"`.

`new_array` is initialised with the first element of `coords_array` and the other ones are added with the loop only if the `coords_array` `"lat"` is greater than the `"lat"` of `new_array` last element.

So `new_array` is:

```
new_array
array([[6, 2],
       [4, 3],
       [2, 6]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: That repeated  `vstack` is not good numpy.  Can you build a list of lists instead?

Comment: @hpaulj yes that's fine

Comment: Give us a [mcve], preferably starting with `coords_array`.  I assume that's a 2d array (n,m).  Is `coords_array[:,1]` sorted?  Rather making a new array (or list) incrementally, have you considered removing the rows that aren't in order?

Comment: `apply...` is no better than an iteration.  It still applies the lambda for each row (axis 0) of the array.  It initializes a result array, and fills in values based the row by row calculation.  That use of walrus and vstack doesn't make sny sense.

Comment: Think of `apply...` as an array version of list cmprehension or map - applying the function to one 1d slice (row) at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pandas method:

```
import pandas as pd
df.sort_values('lon', ascending = False).loc[lambda x: x['lat'].cummax() == x['lat']]

   lon  lat
3    6    2
0    4    3
6    2    6
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```py
import numpy as np

# prepare example data in which first column is sorted
rng = np.random.default_rng(258494252)
x = rng.integers(100, size=(100, 2))
x[:, 0] = np.sort(x[:, 0])[::-1]

# if your data is already sorted by the first column, start here
# find running maximum value in second column
y = np.maximum.accumulate(x[:, 1])

# keep only the rows for which it increases
i = np.diff(y, prepend=-np.inf) > 0
x[i]
# array([[98, 47],
#        [97, 71],
#        [97, 82],
#        [94, 89],
#        [87, 99]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think this is what I am looking for. If I understand correctly your code you are sorting the first column independently to the second one, which means mixing the longitude and latitude of the points. If I run your code using my example, I obtain: `[[6, 3], [1, 6]]` and these points are not in the original dataframe

Comment: I was just preparing data for processing rather than running the minimal example. Don't include the sort in my answer when you run on your data, which you said is already sorted by the first column. Start with "find running maximum...".